# Wait for process to finish before going to the next line in shell script

Tags: shell-script, tar

I have a script I made to create a backup. I need to make sure the backup is ready before it runs the `/home/ftp.sh` command. How can I do so? I use CentOS 5.6

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -Pcf /home/temp_backup.tar /home/myfiles/
wait %%
/home/ftp.sh
```

Comment: Currently you don't have any programs backgrounded, so your invocation of `wait` makes no sense. How are you defining "backup is ready"? It looks fine to me in its current state (although the spurious `wait` is unnecessary).

Comment: I mean wait untill tar -Pcf /home/temp_backup.tar /home/myfiles/
 finish because its huge folder might take up to minute and only when its finished run /home/ftp.sh

Comment: we understand what you mean, @Hujeplet, but what @chris-down was saying is that your `tar` command is not being backgrounded, so the script has no choice but to wait for it to finish before executing the `/home/ftp.sh` script.

Comment: @Hujeplet - But it already does that...

Answer (score 11):

You're already doing it.

Waiting for a command to finish is the shell's normal behavior. (Try typing `sleep 5` at a shell prompt.) The only time that *doesn't* happen is when you append `&` to the command, or when the command itself does something to effectively background itself (the latter is a bit of an oversimplification).

You can delete the `wait %%` command from your script; it probably just produces an error message like `wait: %%: no such job`.  (Question: does it actually print such a message?)

Do you have any evidence that the `tar` command *isn't* completing before the `/home/ftp.sh` command starts?

Incidentally, it's a bit odd to have things other than users' home directories directly under `/home`.

(I know most of this was already covered in comments, but I thought there should be an actual answer.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
wait $!
```

Delete the `wait %%` from your script.

Comment: As explained in [Keith's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26526/73), any wait command is completely unnecessary.